# What are meaningful properties of a comparison of 2 CDFs?

Tags: statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

It's been a while since I've done inferential statistics. I'd appreciate kick-start.

I made performance observations that I could line up to f<sub>1</sub> as illustrated in the attached photo.

Afterwards I changed the system and measured again and the performance obervations were faster. See f<sub>2</sub>. Now, I want to make as many meaningful statements as possible.

1. most important: configuration<sub>2</sub> is significantly
   "faster" than configuration<sub>1</sub>. Is that Anova?
2. variance and the mean of the two in comparison
3. demarcate outliers in a meaningfull number? I need this to proof that here are no hickups (outliers) in the system. (in a graph, it's boxplot, I recall)
4. others you could think of?

   [image]

Comment: 1. You should look up "first order stochastic dominance" (FOSD). Here, $f_1$ fosd' $f_2$, as the probability of having to "wait" a longer time than $t$ under the distribution $f_1$ (namely, $1-f_1(t)$) is higher than under distribution $f_2$ for any value of $t$. In particular, this implies for 2. that the mean waiting time will be higher under $f_1$.

Comment: 0. Use `f` for PDFs and `F` for CDFs, not `f` for CDFs.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I looked at this example here and to me it seems like like the result is binary. On stochastically dominates another. Is there nothing that gives proportional value of variance? e.g. (variance of f2 - variance of f1)  / variance of f1

http://people.duke.edu/~dgraham/ECO_463/Handouts/StochasticDominance.pdf